# WCF custom DataContract/DataMember and CA1811: Avoid uncalled private code

Tags: c#, wcf, class, datacontract, datamember

I got a WCF service, and one of the return objects is:

```
[DataContract]
sealed class Class1
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Prop1 { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

Incidentially, one of the properties, let's say it's this `Prop1`, I only set within the service, and then read in the client.

This, however, produces `CA1811: Avoid uncalled private code` on the `.get()` of `Prop1`.

Am I doing something wrong, or should I ignore this warning, or should I do something differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really doing anything wrong. The warning is raised because the getter is never called on the service side; which is where the analyzed code resides. I think you can safely ignore the warning